# Kotlin: How to get lists from an Arraylist?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, kotlin, filter

Here is a simple `ArrayList`:

```
private val fruits = arrayListOf(
    FruitsInBox("Apple", "Korea", "2ea"),
    FruitsInBox("Mango", "India", "1ea"),
    FruitsInBox("Strawberry", "Australia", "1ea"),
    FruitsInBox("Kiwi", "NewZealand", "2ea"),
    FruitsInBox("Peach", "Korea", "3ea")
)
```

And, I want to filter the data by the number of fruits, like below.

```
private var numberOfFruits = arrayOf("All", "1ea", "2ea", "3ea", "4ea")
```

However, I hope to put the things `"All", "1ea", "2ea", "3ea", "4ea"` from the `ArrayList`, automatically.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you shou us the class `FruitsInBox`? You have to `map` and `filter` by the attribute that holds those values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of how to get a list of the third attributes of the `FruitsInBox`.

```
// definition of the class FruitsInBox
data class FruitsInBox(val name: String, val country: String, val quantity: String)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // your example data
    val fruits = arrayListOf(
        FruitsInBox("Apple", "Korea", "2ea"),
        FruitsInBox("Mango", "India", "1ea"),
        FruitsInBox("Strawberry", "Australia", "1ea"),
        FruitsInBox("Kiwi", "NewZealand", "2ea"),
        FruitsInBox("Peach", "Korea", "3ea")
    )

    /*
     * since "All" is not a quantity derived from an instance of FruitsInBox,
     * you have to add it manually, so create a list containing only the String "All"
     */
    val allFruitQuantities = mutableListOf("All")

    // then get the distinct quantities sorted in a list
    val fruitQuantities = fruits.map { it -> it.quantity }
                                .distinct()
                                .sorted()
                                .toList()

    // add the sorted list of distinct values to the one containing "All"
    allFruitQuantities.addAll(fruitQuantities)

    // print the result
    println(allFruitQuantities)
}
```

The output is

```
[All, 1ea, 2ea, 3ea]
```

Comment: Cool! thanks mate! But, if I want to get the output without repetition, how can I do?

Comment: It's not really an id when apple/kiwi and mango/strawberry share the same value no? @SeanKim to get a list without repetition you can call `.distinct()` on it.

Comment: @RobCo of course, it isn't, but that little incorrectness wasn't really critical here...

Comment: it's not ID, it is just quantity of the fruits. :)

Comment: Wow! one more! Can I put "All"? and Can it be listed in numerical order? like 1ea, 2ea, 3ea?

Comment: @SeanKim have a look at the new, minimized answer

Comment: @deHaar I got error, 'Expecting member declaration' on  `allFruitQuantities.addAll(fruitQuantities)` part..

Comment: @SeanKim That's possibly because you should have a class member and my examples are all local variables, use the one of your example... Maybe declare it as `private var numberOfFruits = mutableListOf("All")` and then simply add the mapped and sorted values.